# how to display nodes information with a JSON request?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I know how to use the API to perform simple request such as display node information selecting node by labels value.

For example : curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/nodes?labelSelector=kubernetes.io/role%3Dworker3
Display informations about node whose role is worker3.

Is there a way to perform the same request using a JSON query ?

looked on the web to find a such example but did not find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query with kubectl by label.
The Roles of the node are just labels.

To return in yaml format

```
 kubectl get nodes -l node-role.kubernetes.io/worker -o yaml
```

To return in json format

```
 kubectl get nodes -l node-role.kubernetes.io/worker -o json
```

**Update**

Querying the api with json you can do like so:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/nodes?{"node.kubernetes.io/worker01":"worker01"}
```

This in my case returns this:

```
{
  "kind": "NodeList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "resourceVersion": "317238"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "worker01",
        "uid": "a2bec224-361f-49e9-8bba-b3b172816d6e",
        "resourceVersion": "316653",
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-12-24T11:04:43Z",
        "labels": {
          "beta.kubernetes.io/arch": "amd64",
          "beta.kubernetes.io/os": "linux",
          "kubernetes.io/arch": "amd64",
          "kubernetes.io/hostname": "worker01",
          "kubernetes.io/os": "linux",
          "microk8s.io/cluster": "true",
          "node.kubernetes.io/microk8s-worker": "microk8s-worker"
        },

............
```

As you can see it works, but you must analyse 2 things generally.

1. the api version (can be different to v1, depends on the kubernetes version)
2. the labels and property name.

The example above comes from microk8s, here i havent even Roles defined.

```
kubectl get node
NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master     Ready    <none>   17d   v1.25.4
worker01   Ready    <none>   17d   v1.25.4
```

So i looked for some label that could extract the required data.

Comment: Indeed @ralle-mc-black. But I guess that what is possible with kubectl is doable by the REST API and especially by a GET request with a JSON body.

Comment: I updated it with a json query example.

Comment: a great thanks. I deploy kubernetes 1.25.0-00  and the api version is v1.

Comment: Could you also upvote my answer please.

Comment: I have not enough reputation for that if I understand correctly.

Comment: I understand, maybe you can do taht later, thanks.

Comment: Sure. The stackoverflow comment explains that my upvote is not possible but kept for "later".